# Read multiple parquet files and ignore _delta_log folder and save in a single csv file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have copied a source to adls using ADF in folder 2022-12-05(SchedulerunTime parameter) and the data looks like one _delta_log folder and many parquet files(refer screenshot) e.g.,
_delta_log,
part-0000-12...,
part-0000-25...,
.... so on

I want to read only the parquet files and write into a single csv file under the same 2022-12-05 and also delete the _delta_log folder.

**Problem :** _delta_log,
part-0000-12...,
part-0000-25...,
.... so on

**Solution I need** : csv_file.csv

**My approach :**
saving in single csv file : DF0.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save(path)

but the output is coming like 1 folder and 3 files  :
*delta_log folder,
SUCCESS* file,
_Committed file,
part-0000-36gdh....csv file.

I only want csv_file.csv removing the 1 folder and these upper 3 files.[image]

Comment: Spark will not write into single CSV file. Actually no big data engine writes in single file. You will have to write your own solution for this.

Comment: Any way we can remove this _delta_log folder?

Comment: Spark does not do anythin related to delta on its own. You must be doing something related to delta in your code or Spark cluster setup which is producing the delta log. This is compleltely specific to  your code and Spark environment. It might also be coming from some azure-data-factory's Databricks configuration.

Comment: part-0000-36gdh....csv file is the one that contains your data. You have to deal with that name. Just make sure that when you are reading the file, your solution will recognize it

Answer (score 0):

If you do the above operations in Pyspark, you can get a single csv file by using `pandas` in databricks.

In Scala, we cannot use `pandas` so you can try this alternative using ADF to get single csv file.

First in source use wildcard file paths and give like `*.parquet`.

These are my source parquet files.

[image]

**Copy activity:**

[image]

In sink use csv file and give **merge** as copy type.

[image]

**Result single csv file:**

[image]